# Jython 2.7 with Java 1.8 - Import custom jar

Tags: java, python, jar, jython, jython-2.7

I'm using jython 2.7 with java, with the objective of creating a python wrapper around my jar file (let's call it `myJar.jar`)

**Here's my python file:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/pathTo/myJar.jar')
from java.lang import Math #this works
from java.io import File # this works`

from com.myPackage.classes import myClass

print('trying to import myClass')
```

I run the following command to execute this code:

`java -jar  ~/pathTo/jython.jar jyTest.py`

I get an importError stating: `ImportError: No module named myPackage`

aside from using `sys.path.append()`, I've also tried:

`java -jar  ~/pathTo/jython.jar  -Dpython.path=/pathTo/myJar.jar  jyTest.py`

and

`java -cp ~/pathTo/jython.jar:~/pathTo/myJar.jar jyTest.py`

and

`java -classpath ~/pathTo/myJar.jar -jar ~/pathTo/jython.jar  jyTest.py`

I also tried using `java -cp` by exporting `myJar.jar` to `$CLASSPATH`.

**None of the above approaches worked.**

Please note that if I do not add the line `from com.myPackage.classes import myClass`, I can see the print statement being executed, therefore, my jython.jar is working as expected.

I installed jython 2.7 **Standalone** package, as per the instructions given on:
https://wiki.python.org/jython/InstallationInstructions

...therefore I only have `jython.jar`

**How should I make `myJar.jar` visible to my python file ?** Thanks

Comment: I just tried this and it works for me.  But, I can get exactly the same kind of `ImportError` if I `mkdir com` in the current directory and re-run the exact same test.  (This is place where the Java way of doing packages and the Python way of doing packages clash a bit.)

Comment: I should add that the `-jar` and `-classpath` options to `java` are mutually exclusive, but `java` doesn't actually tell you that they are.

Comment: sys.path.append works in jython 2.2, but not in 2.7. Using 2.2 solved it for me

Comment: The fact that 2.2 worked by 2.7 didn't is surprising.  I tested on 2.7.

Comment: Same here 2.7 does not work. Sadly